# Flyout navigation controller menu indicator

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am using the Flyout navigation component in my Xamarin IOS application and I am able to connect multiple view controllers to it and also swipe out left and able to see the menu items. But I am not getting a menu indicator at the top as like in the drawer menu applications(like facebook and many android apps). Here is the code I used

```
    FlyoutNavigationController navController = new FlyoutNavigationController {//this will create a new instance of the FlyoutComponent
            NavigationRoot = new RootElement("Menu"){ //Here we create the root of the alements
                new Section("Seccion 1"){
                    new StringElement("Picks"),
                    new StringElement("Watchlist"),
                },
                new Section("Seccion 2"){
                    new StringElement("Portfolio"),
                },
            },
            ViewControllers =  new [] {//here we link Controllers
                this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("Picks") as UIViewController,//here we create the instances for the Controllers
                this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("Watchlist") as UIViewController,
                this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("Portfolio") as UIViewController,
            }
        };
//navController.ToggleMenu();
        View.AddSubview (navController.View);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out that I have to set the left bar button item with an image looking like a drawer menu like this

```
UIBarButtonItem menuIndicator = new UIBarButtonItem (UIImage.FromBundle   ("images/slideout.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, e) => {
            AppDelegate.FlyoutNavigation.ToggleMenu ();
        });
        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (menuIndicator, false);
```

Comment: What is "Picks","Watchlist etc"? To be more precise" - which property of the view controller on storyboard view do You assign with "Picks" idetifier?

Comment: thats the Storboard ID for that ViewController

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my code "this.storyboard" is null. Did you drag and drop on storyboard only view controllers or also flyout navigation controller?

Comment: I dragged and dropped only the ViewControllers. I added FlyoutNaviagationController in Code. My app has a login screen and post successfull login I push the flyout viewcontroller which i created in code. It shows the first viewcontroller by default.

Comment: Still doesnt work. Would you mind sending my some code snippent or sample solution?

Comment: sure, i will try to put a sample and add in github

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. check this https://github.com/appcodr/StockSuggest/tree/master/StockSuggest.IOS